# Adding Event Listener to a nested <input> HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

```
 const form = document.getElementById("form")
 const input = form.querySelectorAll(":scope > .guessSubmit")

 input.addEventListener("submit", compareUserGuess)
```

```
 1 <!DOCTYPE html>
  2 <html lang="en">
  3 <head>
  4     <meta charset="UTF-8">
  5     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  6     <title>Number Guesser</title>
  7     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  8     <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  9 </head>
 10 <body>
 11   <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
 12   <p>There is a predisposed selected integer between 1 and 100. Your objective
 13   is to guess this integer within 10 attemtps. Good luck, will you need it?</p>
 14   <form id="form">
 15     <div id="text-label">
 16       <label for="example">Enter a guess</label>
 17       <input id="example" type="text" name="text"/>
 18     </div>
 19     <div id="submit-label">
 20       <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" accesskey="s"
 21                    class="guessSubmit"/>
 22     </div>
 23     </form>
 24 </body>
 25 </html>
```

Hello, I am trying to grab the  element with the "guessSubmit" attribute inside of the parent  element in the HTML, to add an event listener that calls the function compareUserGuess upon submission in JS.

The error that I receive from this code is script.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: input.addEventListener is not a function. I'm not sure if it is something with the rendering, or if I am simply not pulling the element correctly from the document. Thanks for any help

I have tried pulling the element from the HTML body in different ways. Using querySelector(), querySelectorAll() with a path to the target element in the arguments. I have even tried using :scope, however I am not able add my EventListener correctly.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns an array of matched nodes. Use `input[0].addEventListener`